# Were any of the stories used in "Star Trek: The Animated Series" rejected from the TV show?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-tas

I have just started watching *Star Trek: The Animated Series* and was wondering if any of the stories come from unused scripts from TOS? So far it is as fun and camp as the TV show and the few episodes I have seen certainly fit with the original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were in fact a few episodes that had their plots drawn from material rejected for *Star Trek: The Original Series*, primarily episodes that served as sequels to previous ones. The episodes *[More Troubles, More Tribbles](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/More_Tribbles,_More_Troubles_(episode))*, *[The Magicks of Megas-tu](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Magicks_of_Megas-Tu_(episode))*, *[Once Upon a Planet](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Planet_(episode))*, and *[Mudd's Passion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mudd%27s_Passion_(episode))* were all originally conceived as episodes of *The Original Series*, though several of them were nothing more than a vague plot suggestion rather than a full script.